# Why does DBD::CSV complain about "Loose unescaped quote"?

Tags: perl, csv, dbi

Why does reading from __DATA__ work and reading from the file doesn't (Loose unescaped quote)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict; use 5.010;
use DBI;

my $table = 'klassik_CD.csv';
print qx(cat $table);

print qq{\n"data" or "Enter" : };
chomp( my $aw = <> );

if ( $aw eq 'data' ) {
    $table = 'te_mp_fi_le.csv';
    open my $fh, '>', $table or die $!;
    while ( defined( my $row = <DATA> ) ) {
    print $fh $row;
    }
    close $fh or die $!;
}

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:CSV:", { RaiseError => 1 } );
$dbh->{csv_tables}{$table} = { col_names => [], sep_char => ';' };

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table" );
$sth->execute;
while ( defined( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) ) {
    say $row->{col1};
}

__DATA__
1;"Kammermusik fuer Blaeser";16;"DG";"eloquence";"dc129610"
2;"Requiem – Laudate Dominum Exultate, jubilate";19;"DG";"eloquence";"0a11f513"
```

Output: "data"
1;"Kammermusik fuer Blaeser";16;"DG";"eloquence";"dc129610"
2;"Requiem – Laudate Dominum Exultate,   jubilate";19;"DG";"eloquence";"0a11f513"

"data" or "Enter" : data
Kammermusik fuer Blaeser
Requiem – Laudate Dominum Exultate, jubilate

---

Output: "Enter"
1;"Kammermusik fuer Blaeser";16;"DG";"eloquence";"dc129610"
2;"Requiem – Laudate Dominum Exultate, jubilate";19;"DG";"eloquence";"0a11f513"

"data" or "Enter" :
DBD::CSV::st execute failed:
Execution ERROR: Error 2034 while reading file ./klassik_CD.csv: EIF - Loose unescaped quote at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/DBD/CSV.pm line 220
.

[for Statement "SELECT * FROM klassik_CD.csv"] at ./zzzzzzzzzz.pl line 27.
DBD::CSV::st fetchrow_hashref failed: Attempt to fetch row without a preceeding execute () call or from a non-SELECT statement [for Statement "SELECT * FROM klassik_CD.csv"] at ./zzzzzzzzzz.pl line 28.

Comment: @rjh Thx, it was not my intention to write "printf".

Comment: @Zaid Does "use utf8" influence the __DATA__-reading?

Comment: Is it obeying the sep_char => ';' correctly?

Comment: Not sure about reading in from `__DATA__`, but I've had this issue in the past with reading and writing wide-body characters to and from files. That `ü` and `ä` may be the issue. Try to read it in without those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I rename the file from "klassik_CD.csv" to "klassik_cd.csv" (all lowercase) it works (though there was no such message as "file not found" ).